# How can I create an empty variable based on another data type in Python?

Tags: python

How can I create empty variable that has the same data type of another variable?

```
   data = get_data()
   new_variable = data.data_type()  #just create empty variable
```

In the above case, if `data` is a list then `new_variable` will be `list()`

Comment: Note that this doesn't generally make sense in Python; variables don't have types, they just refer to values. Values have types. So what you're asking for is to get an empty **value** of the same type as another value. Not all types have a concept of an "empty" value. However container types do, and Ignacio's answer should work for most of them, as they generally also have zero-argument constructors that produce an empty container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the class of the value, invoke the constructor with no arguments, and hope that it doesn't blow up.

```
data.__class__()
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `type(data)()`.